# How to output image and download using php

Tags: php, image, download

Is it possible to render/output an image using php and force a download, without saving the image to the server?

I've looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php and can render the image and save the image using `imagejpeg();`

I've tried creating a hyperlink to the saved image on the server and forcing a download using `download`.

Just wondering if there was a easier/simpler method?

Comment: But the solution with the hyperlink is already simple.

Comment: you want to download images from another source using php ?

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior I’d prefer not to save the images on the server

Comment: @Noman no I’d be creating the image from a script

Comment: Then you must need to use `imagejpeg`

Comment: What about a method to automate the download *without* the link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `imagejpeg()` to output the image to the browser. ([Docs](https://secure.php.net/imagejpeg))

```
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($image);
```

When you leave out the second parameter of `imagejpeg()` or set it to `null` the image will be sent to the browser (in binary form).

To trigger the download in the browser, you need to set another header value:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="YourFilenameHere.jpg"');
```

This tells the browser, that it should download the file as `YourFilenameHere.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this code if the file is in another directory:

```
 $file = 'test.png';
 $filepath = "images/" . $file;


    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); 
        readfile($filepath);
        exit;
    }
```